# Clearing the console buffer in a Windows Forms Application

Tags: c#, winforms, console

I have a WinForms application that creates a Console Window using AllocConsole() from kernel32.dll; so basically I cannot use most of the methods from System.Console, to solve this I'm using other WinApi functions (Like SetWindowPos,SetWindowText,ect....) to play with the Console Window, but I cannot seem to find a way to clear the console. Can anyone help me with achieve this?